# How to run Ag asynchronously with vimproc and quickrun - VIM?

Tags: asynchronous, vim, ag

I'm using [Ag](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim), [vimproc](https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim), [quickrun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun)

I'm able to run `.php` asynchronously with this settings in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>r :QuickRun<CR>
let g:quickrun_config = get(g:, 'quickrun_config', {})
let g:quickrun_config = {
\   "_" : {
\       'runner':                    'vimproc',
\       'runner/vimproc/updatetime': 60,
\       'outputter/quickfix':        ':quickrun-module-outputter/quickfix',
\       'outputter/buffer/split':    ':rightbelow 8sp',
\   },
\}
```

Does anyone know how can I run `ag` asynchronously?

`Ag` settings in `.vimrc`

```
if executable("ag")
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -i --nocolor --nogroup --hidden
    \ --ignore .git
    \ --ignore .svn
    \ --ignore .hg
    \ --ignore .DS_Store
    \ --ignore "**/*.pyc"
    \ -g ""'
endif
nnoremap <leader>a :Ag!<Space>
nnoremap <leader>aa :Ag! <C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>aaa :Ag! <C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution to use asynchronous command with Vim is using a plugin called [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch), you can launch command in the background with `:Start!`

Alternatively, this is also a fork of vim called [neovim](https://neovim.io/), which is trying to address that issue. At the time of this post, it is not necessarily mature enough, but this is something to consider as well for the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. neovim looks very promising.